Numerically stable calculation of eigenvector derivatives for repeated eigenvalues
Let us consider a real symmetric matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of multiplicity $m$. Furthermore, let $\mathbf{X}=[\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_2,\ldots, \mathbf{x}_m]$ be a matrix with $m$ linearly independent eigenvectors associated to $\lambda$.
I would like to calculate the $\dot{\mathbf{X}}$ derivative with respect to a single variable $t$. It is well known from https://doi.org/10.1002/nme.6442 that
$\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{A}-\lambda \mathbf{I} & -\mathbf{X} \newline
-\mathbf{X}^{\rm T} & \mathbf{0}
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
\dot{\mathbf{X}} \\ \newline
\mathbf{D}
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
-\dot{\mathbf{A}}\mathbf{X} \\ \newline
\mathbf{0}
\end{pmatrix} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)
\end{equation}
$
provides a "well-defined" $\dot{\mathbf{X}}$ vector, where $\mathbf{D}=\mathbf{X}^{\rm T}\dot{\mathbf{A}} \mathbf{X}$.
My question is the following: could this linear system of two matrix equations be reduced to a single matrix equation in the form
$$(\mathbf{A}-\lambda \mathbf{I} + \mu \mathbf{X} \mathbf{X}^{\rm T})\mathbf{\dot{X}} = \mathbf{\dot{A}X} + \mathbf{X}\mathbf{D}? \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$
Here the second equation is added to the first one by using $\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^{\rm T}\mathbf{\dot{X}} = \mathbf{0}$ due to
$\mathbf{X}^{\rm T}\mathbf{\dot{X}} = \mathbf{0}$.
If this single equation is equivalent to the original version, how to chose $\mu$ to avoid numerical instability?
Edit
(a) The cited paper is available here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340828105.
(b) This reference provides the following equation (for a generalized eigenvalue problem) under Eq. (A5):
$\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{K}-\lambda \mathbf{M} & -\mathbf{M\Phi} \newline
-\mathbf{\Phi}^{\rm T}\mathbf{M} & \mathbf{0}
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{Z'\Gamma}^{\rm T} \\ \newline
\mathbf{\Gamma\Lambda'\Gamma}^{\rm T}
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
-(\mathbf{K'}-\lambda\mathbf{M}')\mathbf{\Phi} \\ \newline
\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{\Phi}^{\rm T}\mathbf{M}'\mathbf{\Phi}
\end{pmatrix} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (A5)
\end{equation}
$
If we apply the following replacements:
$\mathbf{K} = \mathbf{A}$,
$\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{I}$,
$\mathbf{\Phi} = \mathbf{X}$,
$\mathbf{Z}'\mathbf{\Gamma}^{\rm T} = \mathbf{\Phi}' = \mathbf{\dot{X}}$,
$\mathbf{D} = \mathbf{\Gamma\Lambda'\Gamma}^{\rm T} = \mathbf{\Phi}^{\rm T}(\mathbf{K'}-\lambda\mathbf{M}')\mathbf{\Phi}$ [see also Eq. (22) in the paper],
$\mathbf{K'} = \dot{\mathbf{A}}$, and
$\mathbf{M}' = \mathbf{0}$,
then we obtain Eq. (1) of my post. Note also that the sign of $-\mathbf{\Phi}^{\rm T}\mathbf{M}$ can be removed in Eq. (1) due to $\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{\Phi}^{\rm T}\mathbf{M}'\mathbf{\Phi} = \mathbf{0}$, but then symmetry is not preserved.

Have you attempted to work on the Jordan-blocks equivalent matrix ?

The referenced paper is directly accessible here


So your matrix $A$ is in fact a $A(t)$ where each entry is differentiable wrt to variable $t$. The same for $X=X(t)$. 2) When you say "it is well known...", I don't see in which precise paragraph of the article I find this result.


Me again : condition $X^T\dot{X}=0$ looks to me very strong ... all the column vectors of $X$ would be orthogonal to all the columns of $\dot{X}$ ?

@JeanMarie Thanks for your comments. I have edited my question, including some additional details. My first equation comes from Eq. (A5) of the cited paper after some adaptation (this article deals with generalized eigenvalue equations, which further complicates the problem). It would be useful to use a single equation for all eigenpairs via the eigendecomposition $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{X\Lambda X}^{\rm T}$, but the papers treat this problem separately for eigensubspace.
